# How to determine socket resource has completed buffering?

Tags: php, sockets

Firing a command to socket resource and getting the output takes some decent amount of time in PHP.

I have written code to read the buffered output string after sleep duration of 1 second and it works fine.
If i don't provide any delay after fputs, i don't get any string.

How to determine this time? putting time duration by hit and trial can cause trouble.
For safe side i always put time in seconds.

What parameters affect this time, does anyone has statistical data?

```
$socket = fsockopen($ip,3083);
$command = 'RTRV-NE-GEN:::123;';
fputs($socket,$command);
sleep(1);
$string = fread( $socket, 3000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to do [`fflush($socket);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php) there after you do `fputs(...)`.